# Why Clustered Index Seek works slow?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    [ID], [geom] AS geom , [Label], [Style] 
FROM  
    [ogc].[0006000004C9]
WHERE 
    [geom] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [geom].STIsValid() = 1 
    AND ([geom].STArea() = 0 OR [geom].STArea() > 79.3734125) 
    AND ([geom].STLength() = 0  OR [geom].STLength() > 39.68670625)
    AND [geom].STIntersects(@g) = 1
```

Table contains ~700 000 rows. And query returns ~70 000 rows and takes 9 seconds to run.

In the Execution Plan, I see that spatial operation (`STIntersects()`) takes only 1%. But clustered index seek takes 71%.

[image]

Inside this seek:

[image]

Here my PK:

```
ALTER TABLE [ogc].[0006000004C9] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_0006000004C9] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

What is extended index this is my PK or query ignore it? How can I improve the execution time?

Other info:

- SQL Server 2014
- Compatibility Level 120

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [ogc].[0006000004C9]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [geom] [GEOMETRY] NOT NULL,
    [Object_ID] [CHAR](12) NOT NULL,
    [Sector_ID] [CHAR](12) NOT NULL,
    [Style] [CHAR](12) NOT NULL,
    [StyleName] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Label] [VARCHAR](80) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_0006000004C9] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**UPDATE**
WHen i remove STIntersection() my query:

```
    SELECT 
    [ID], [geom] AS geom , [Label], [Style] 
FROM  
    [ogc].[0006000004C9]
WHERE 
    [geom] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [geom].STIsValid() = 1 
    AND ([geom].STArea() = 0 OR [geom].STArea() > 79.3734125) 
    AND ([geom].STLength() = 0  OR [geom].STLength() > 39.68670625)
    AND [geom].STIntersects(@g) = 1
```

In plan i see:

```
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

And it's so nice. Actual and Estimeted is same, no any extended indexes. And query takes only `8 seconds`. So with  `STIntersects` query works `9 seconds`. So 8 seconds it is normal situation or it slow and there is any ways to inprove it?

Comment: We have no idea how this view is defined or structured.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i'd added table structure.

Comment: The 71% is only an *estimate* before the query is performed. Can you get the actual cost?

Comment: Previously you were querying `something_view` rather than `something` and I see you've removed columns from the select clause. Does this generate the same problematic plan? Because you've not up-dated that image.

Comment: If you look at the execution plan detail, you see that the optimizer has "Estimated number of rows = 1", but in reality it's "Actual number of rows = 408191". That's a **massive** disconnect between estimation and reality  - typically a sign of  outdated statistics. I'd recommend to refresh all the relevant statistics, and then try again

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah previosly i copy query what use view as target, but  tried to make question more clearly and revrite query to make it use table as target. querys take same time and procentage in plan.

Comment: @marc_s It's mean i gonna jsut delete statstic and recreate it?

Comment: Just **update** the statistics - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 - no need to "delete and recreate" ....

Comment: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/what-caused-that-plan-to-go-horribly-wrong-should-you-update-statistics/

Comment: @marc_s i run `UPDATE STATISTICS [ogc].[0006000004C9];  ` after run my query but still see same numbers in Estimeted and Actual rows

Comment: I suspect it's the `OR` conditions that is making your seek look at a lot of rows and then filter most of them away. I don't play with spatial at all, but I wonder if you could have a filtered index `WHERE STArea() = 0 AND STLength() = 0` and then perform a `UNION ALL` instead of the `OR`...

Comment: Try to update **ALL** statistics  (at least on all tables involved) - not just this single one .....

Comment: I'm curious about a couple of things. 1) What does your spatial index look like? 2) What are you trying to accomplish with what appear to be magic numbers in your predicates on `STArea()` and `STLength()` (i.e. why check if each of those equal zero or are greater than some very specific number)? If I were trying to hack this, I might promote `STArea()` and `STLength()` and `STIsValid()` to computed columns and try to include them in your spatial index. And, specific to `STIsValid()`, is there any way you can prevent *invalid* data in your table and skip that predicate completely?